# Access JSON node attributes using node id in Cytoscape

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, cytoscape.js

I am trying to display all json data for a node in cytoscape, when the node is clicked. So far, I am able to identify the id attribute of the selected node. Code is below:

```
cy.on('tap', 'node', function(evt){
  var clicked = 'clicked' + ' ' + evt.target.id();
  document.getElementById("nodeInfo").innerHTML = clicked;
});
```

My webpage will display the id of the clicked node, but now I need to somehow use the ID of the selected node to display the rest of that nodes attributes. Any ideas? Here is one of my nodes from the JSON file.

```
{
  "data": {
    "id":"1",
    "business_id":"6iYb2HFDywm3zjuRg0shjw",
    "name":"Oskar Blues Taproom",
    "address":"921 Pearl St",
    "city":"Boulder",
    "state":"CO",
    "postal_code":"80302",
    "latitude":40.0175444,
    "longitude":-105.2833481,
    "stars":4.0,"review_count":86,
    "is_open":1,
    "attributes": {
      "RestaurantsTableService":"True",
      "WiFi":"u'free'",
      "BikeParking":"True",
      "BusinessParking":"{'garage': False, 'street': True, 'validated': False, 'lot': False, 'valet': False}",
      "BusinessAcceptsCreditCards":"True",
      "RestaurantsReservations":"False",
      "WheelchairAccessible":"True",
      "Caters":"True",
      "OutdoorSeating":"True",
      "RestaurantsGoodForGroups":"True",
      "HappyHour":"True",
      "BusinessAcceptsBitcoin":"False",
      "RestaurantsPriceRange2":"2",
      "Ambience":"{'touristy': False, 'hipster': False, 'romantic': False, 'divey': False, 'intimate': False, 'trendy': False, 'upscale': False, 'classy': False, 'casual': True}",
      "HasTV":"True",
      "Alcohol":"'beer_and_wine'",
      "GoodForMeal":"{'dessert': False, 'latenight': False, 'lunch': False, 'dinner': False, 'brunch': False, 'breakfast': False}",
      "DogsAllowed":"False",
      "RestaurantsTakeOut":"True",
      "NoiseLevel":"u'average'",
      "RestaurantsAttire":"'casual'",
      "RestaurantsDelivery":"None"
    },
    "categories":"Gastropubs, Food, Beer Gardens, Restaurants, Bars, American (Traditional), Beer Bar, Nightlife, Breweries",
    "hours":{
      "Monday":"11:0-23:0",
      "Tuesday":"11:0-23:0",
      "Wednesday":"11:0-23:0",
      "Thursday":"11:0-23:0",
      "Friday":"11:0-23:0",
      "Saturday":"11:0-23:0",
      "Sunday":"11:0-23:0"
    }
  }
```

How can I gain access to the rest of the node's data attributes?